# Field jwtFilter required a bean of type 'filter.JwtFilter' that could not be found.?

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I want to start my spring app after i made some jwt authentification configuration. but i have this issues :

Description:

```
Field jwtFilter in com.soheibKehal.CashApi.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'filter.JwtFilter' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'filter.JwtFilter' in your configuration.
```

The thing is in my SecurityConfig class, i already Beaned my AuthentificationManager method, so i dont know what is the problem ?

```
    package com.soheibKehal.CashApi.config;

import com.soheibKehal.CashApi.services.CustomUserDetailService;
import filter.JwtFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
            return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }
    
        @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate")
                    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);;
        }
    }
```

my jwtFilter class :

```
  package filter;

import com.soheibKehal.CashApi.Util.JwtUtil;
import com.soheibKehal.CashApi.services.CustomUserDetailService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
    @Component
    public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailService service;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException, IOException, ServletException {
    
            String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
    
            String token = null;
            String userName = null;
    
            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
                userName = jwtUtil.extractUsername(token);
            }
    
            if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
    
                UserDetails userDetails = service.loadUserByUsername(userName);
    
                if (jwtUtil.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
    
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                            .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        }
    }
```

Do you have any idea what is the problem ?

Comment: Is your jwtFilter extending OncePerRequestFilter?

Comment: I edited with my jwt filter as u can see yes ! @OnomeSotu

Comment: Can you check your package structure? What are the package names for your filter and securityConfig class?

Comment: I edited with the package bro ! @OnomeSotu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in your package structure. Springboot will scan your app for autoconfiguration starting from the package where you have a class of this structure

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

It should be in the package `com.soheibKehal.CashApi`.

The solution will be to move the filter package into the `com.soheibKehal.CashApi` just beside your `config` package.

Then spring will be able to locate the `JwtFilter` for autoconfiguration.

Comment: Oh my god , how did i missed that , yeah my package was out... i feel so dumb right now .... thank you

Comment: It happens. Don't beat yourself up about it. Just always create your packages that way for autoconfiguration to work.